# Lenovo T550 TLP - Unable to set Threshold

Tags: lenovo, battery, thinkpad, tlp

Does anybody have experience with Ubuntu on a Lenovo T550, using TLP power management? TLP Should allow for battery thresholds to be set on thinkpads, I have set the threshold correctly but it is still charging to 100%. I have psosted my tlp-stat -b to the TLP github and was told that everything seems fine and that it's hardware related.

Any idea how to fix this?

https://github.com/linrunner/TLP/issues/300#issuecomment-332531231

Thank you